# Free resources to learn computer (electrical?) engineering?

Tags: cpu-architecture

First, I just returned from DEFCON 18 and I am completely inspired to learn more about hardware.  For example, how do I add LEDs to the badge? (http://www.grandideastudio.com/portfolio/defcon-18-badge/) How do I learn how to read the schematic and understand what I can do with it?

I checked out some computer engineering books on Amazon, but they are all really expensive.  I also realize they may not even be what I want.  What are some free resources to learn how to modify hardware?

Also, as a side note, I am fairly well versed in software.  I have also built computers and played around a bit with hardware at a higher level, but I want to dive into a deeper understanding.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not programming related, so it belogs to supersuser.com

Comment: @Robert: not a superuser question - just off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

MIT has many of their classes [free online](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/).  It's really an amazing resource (Physics with Prof. Walter Lewin is a work of art).

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It looks like a great resource.  I can't believe I didn't know about it before.

Answer (score 4):

Electrical engineering (or engineering of any kind) is usually a four-year program at an accredited university in this country.  You take a lot of fundamentals in math, physics, etc. to get that deeper understanding you crave.

It doesn't lend itself to a "Learn Electrical Engineering in 21 Days" approach.

You might mean "I'd like to learn more about electronics".  I think that might be a shorter path.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  "A deeper understanding" at this point, for me, is more akin "I'd like to learn more about electronics".

Comment: It didn't answer my question...

Comment: Voting up means "helpful" or "I liked it".  Being able to mark it as the answer to your question is a separate action.

Answer (score 1):

Crash course on how to learn Electrical Engineering through Googling (items in chronological):

1. You should understand at least this theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws   LEARN ABOUT CURRENT AND VOLTAGE
2. You are most likely interested in digital things.  In that case, you should purchase a microcontroller with a development board.  A good choice for a beginner is an Arduino board.

   To know about LEDs: Always use a resistor in series with an LED (100 - 330 Ohms) as they are "cookie monsters" with current and will burn themselves.  Use 3-5 volts.  They drop around .7 - 1.5V volts.  They only allow charge to flow in one direction (current is moving charges).

   Transistors:http://www.kpsec.freeuk.com/trancirc.htm  Also understand a bit about MOSFETs

   Items 1,2, and 3 should be learned in parallel

   You also want something called  a breadboard.  It will allow you to prototype circuits with ease.

   Guide to package: Through hole packaging chips can usually be used on a breadboard.  Anything else requires soldering

   Op Amps are used in lots of analog circuits.  Popular: LM324, LF356 (LF356 is a good beginner amp).  You should learn about these.

   If you are of the digital persuasion, then get an Altera DE2 FPGA board.  FPGAs are chips which have reprogrammable logic.  You can implement your own graphics card (I've seen it done), processor, and any other hardware you can think of.  Altera tools are great.  Xilinx tools suck but their raw silicon is better than Altera.

   Advanced mode: Phasors, Laplace Transforms, Fourier Transforms

Comment: This is not electrical engineering. Electrical Engineering is circuit analysis and design, signal processing, microelectronics, power electronics, control systems, material science, etc. including mathematics such as calculus, differential equations, advanced engineering mathematics.  What you provide is  quick way to learn electronics sufficient to interact such with software.  As an electrical engineer, I deem this is a shameful post but for electronics tinkering it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Well one start could be googling for sites by hobbyists who build projects based on their microcontroller of choice (butterfly, arduino, propeller, motorola, arm, etc...), if you want to learn how to modify hardware.